# fiware idm sign up email

Tags: authentication, fiware

I have installed FIWARE's IdM KeyRock in a Ubuntu 12.05 virtual machine. Horizon and Keystone are up, but when I try to sign up from localhost:8000, the confirmation email is not sent by KeyRock.

I have install Postfix and I'm using Gmail as SMTP server.

Using mail command, a test mail is sent by Ubuntu and it is delivered to Gmail. However, I'm not able to see if Keyrock is sending any email.

Configuration in Openstack (local_settings.py) is the following:

```
# Configure these for your outgoing email host
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Can anybody help me out on this?

Comment: try adding the settings EMAIL_USE_TLS = True DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'my gmail account'. I will try too and see what could be failing. And remember to check the spam folder too ;)

Comment: would you possibly help to show me how to config idm to send email.

I have idm run in docker container. I shoud run postfix inside container or my host machine?

And where can i put stmp config? Inside idm or postfix

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following configuration in my local machine and successfully sent emails through my gmail.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'APP_PASSWORD!'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com'
```

I think the reason you are not getting any email is because you seem to be  using your account password. You should create a new app password in your Google Accounts page and use the one provided there.

More info on app passwords: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en